# 'Paint' method for HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, paint, html5-canvas

Is there a way of preventing anything drawn to the canvas to be seen until a certain point? I'd like to be able to draw a number of objects at once, then draw over them with another object and a different composite method, on a loop.

Because the first lot of painting takes so long, the result will only be seen for a fraction of a second before it loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal method would be to render those objects into an off-screen `Canvas`, and then use `context.drawImage()` to copy it onto the on-screen one.

Comment: Aha, this is double buffering, isn't it. I vaguely knew about it, but I don't do much on the graphics side, so I'm not too familiar with how it works.

Comment: @Jiminizer kinda, yes.  Strictly speaking double buffering involves _swapping_ two screen buffers, so they each alternate between the off-screen and on-screen roles.